# Namespaces interfering with Classes in PHP - Best Practices?

Tags: php, apache, class, namespaces

**Introduction**

I've been having some trouble using my class objects in PHP alongside my namespace setup. I'm not sure if this is a simple error on my part, or if this is a bad practice, but I'm hoping someone can shed some light onto this subject.

So the first instance is one that works.

**Working Example**

```
<?php
// Our Class
class Car {
    function Car() {
        $this->model = "VW";
    }
}

// create an object
$herbie = new Car();

// show object properties
echo $herbie->model;
?>
```

Taken from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp)

**Issue at Hand**

The issue is when I use a namespace to call that class.

*In index.php*

```
<?php
// Get Class
require 'Magic/Car.php';

// create an object
$herbie = new Magic\Car();

// show object properties
echo $herbie->model;
?>
```

*In Magic/Car.php*

```
<?php
// Our Namespace
namespace Magic;

// Our Class
class Car {
    function Car() {
        $this->model = "VW";
    }
}
?>
```

**Conclusion**

For some reason, in the second example, the `echo $herbie->model;` does not return a value. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: This will teach you to use w3schools.com as a reference. They are woefully out of date in many areas.

Comment: I usually only use them for their examples. What would be your "goto" reference for this?

Comment: I use php.net for my references. There are plenty of examples tehre.

Comment: I just got it working, and the issue seemed to be both on my part, and on w3schools... Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just change `function Car` to `function __construct`.